# Problemas con posicionamiento en css

Tags: javascript, html, html5, css3, xhtml

por que cuando una caja de html la desplazo hasta el fondo la barra de desplazamiento se estira, quiero mandar una caja que no se vea en el html y la mando hacia abajo con un position absolute top 800px pero la barra de desplazamiento se estira y eso no es lo que quiero

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<img src="bat3.png" class="animation">


</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.animation{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 800px;
}
```

Comment: Lo que estas intentando no es possible, talvez seria mejor con un display: none;?

Comment: podrias indicarme como ?

Comment: yo estoy haciendo un efecto de transicion, pero quiero que salga un objeto de abajo hacia arriba y no salga mas como animacion de una pelota que sale de abajo hacia arriba y no vuelve a salir

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh
}

.animation{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Luego en la transición cambias el `opacity:1;` y `display: block;` lograrás el efecto como si viene desde abajo. Aunque yo te recomiendo meter la imagen en un div y aplicar los estilos y transiciones al mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Para que no se vea la barra de desplazamiento, ocúltala:

```
body{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```